# Starting at specific rows, how to carry on their values until a row with a higher value is met?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Assume a pandas Series and a boolean mask that marks certain rows. Exempt the masked values, all others are sorted in ascending order. How can the masked values be written in the rows following up, until a row with a higher value is met?

I'm especially interested in solutions that only use boolean masking and pandas.Series methods instead handling row indices explicitly. Many thanks!

***Example***

Input:

```
values = pd.Series([0.1, 0.15, 0.29, 0.22, 0.24, 0.3, 0.46, 0.5, 0.52, 0.55, 0.81, 0.67, 0.7, 0.81, 0.84, 0.91, 0.93, 0.98, 1.])
mask = pd.Series([False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Output:

```
values = pd.Series([0.1, 0.15, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.3, 0.46, 0.5, 0.52, 0.55, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.84, 0.91, 0.93, 0.98, 1.])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Series` has method [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
values = pd.Series([0.1, 0.15, 0.29, 0.22, 0.24, 0.3, 0.46, 0.5, 0.52, 0.55, 0.81, 0.67, 0.7, 0.81, 0.84, 0.91, 0.93, 0.98, 1.])

values.cummax()

0     0.10
1     0.15
2     0.29
3     0.29
4     0.29
5     0.30
6     0.46
7     0.50
8     0.52
9     0.55
10    0.81
11    0.81
12    0.81
13    0.81
14    0.84
15    0.91
16    0.93
17    0.98
18    1.00
```

Comment: I didn't know - that's perfect! Thank you very much.